# $\{I\}\times V^n$ is a closed submanifold of $O(n)\times V^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lie-groups

> Let $G=O(n)\times V^n$ and define a product in $G$ by $(A,v)(B,w)=(AB,Bv+w)$. Show that $\{I\}\times V^n$, $I$ being the identity matrix, is a closed submanifold and normal subgroup and that $O(n)\times \{0\}$ is a closed submanifold and subgroup $G$.

$O(n)$ stands for the orthogonal group.

I am seeing how to prove this because I cannot develop a map that would be a translation.

If $$F:G\to {I}\times V^n$$
such that $$F(g)= A^{-1}A +v=I+v$$.

$DF$ has full rank on every point, but I cannot find a regular point, that would give me the subgroup $H$.

**Question**: How should I prove the assertion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your notation is a mess and I cannot for the life of me follow what you're saying or trying to do.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment. There was a typo in my definition of $F$

Comment: What is $H$, and why are you trying to map $G$ to it?

Comment: H is the subgroup $\{I\}\times V^n$

Comment: Your approach is still confused. Why are you mapping $G\to H$ if you want to show $H$ is a closed submanifold?

Comment: @TedShifrin If it was the other way around mapping $H\to G$ I could use the fact DF has full rank and each point of G would be regular. From there I could prove that ${I}\times V^n$ is a closed submanifold. $F: H\to G$ such that $F(g)=A\times I +v$, where $g=(I,v)$.

Comment: No, there are no regular values for that mapping (why?). This has nothing to do with manifolds. It is just straight algebra and basic topology.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Is there a continuous group homomorphism $G\to O(n)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin $\pi_1(A,v)=A$ is an homomorphism between $G$ and $O(n)$. The projection over the first coordinate.

Comment: Now finish your problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin     I am still stuck because I would need to find a homomorphism from O(n) to $O(n)\times V^n$. So why start with the homomorphism $\pi_1$ as you suggested?

Comment: No, you get $\{I\}\times V$ immediately from $\pi_1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin            Projecting over the first coordinate, I would have $\pi_1(A,v)=A$ and $A\in O(n)$. Right?

Comment: Yes, sure …. ….

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not seeing how $O(n)=I(n)\times V^n$. Can you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group $G=O(n)\times V^n$ is a trivial vector bundle over $O(n)$ with model fibre $V^n$. In particular, the projection $\pi_{O(n)}:O(n)\times V^n\rightarrow O(n)$ is a smooth submersion (this is true of any smooth fibre bundle, but in the case of trivial ones it's particularly easy to show this), so the inverse image, $\pi_{O(n)}^{-1}(g)$ of any $g\in O(n)$ is an embedded sub manifold.  Furthermore since the singleton set $\{g\}$ is closed in $O(n)$, we have that $\pi_{O(n)}^{-1}(g)$ is closed in $O(n)\times V^n$. It is easy to see that $\pi_{O(n)}^{-1}(g)=\{g\}\times V^n$, so $\{g\}\times V^n$ is a closed embedded submanifold of $G$ for all $g\in O(n)$.

Showing that $\{I\}\times V^n$ is a subgroup of $G$ is easy, since $V^n$ is an abelian group by forgetting the vector space structure, and your group structure on the second coordinate is just vector addition. It follows by Cartans subgroup theorem that $\{I\}\times V^n$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $G$.

To show that $\{I\}$ is normal, let $h=(A,v)$, then $h^{-1}=(A^{-1}, A^{-1}(-v)$ as:

$$h\cdot h^{-1}=(A,v)\cdot (A^{-1},A^{-1}(-v)=(I,A^{-1}v-A^{-1}v)=(I,0) $$

Let $n=(I,w)$, then:

$$gng^{-1}=(A,v+w)(A^{-1},A^{-1}(-v)=(I,A^{-1}(v+w)-A^{-1}v)=(I,A^{-1}w)\in \{I\}\times V^n$$

so $G$ is a normal closed Lie subgroup of $G$.

You can do the same thing for your other case. In particular, $O(n)\times V^n$ is a trivial $O(n)$ bundle over $V^n$, and there is a smooth right action of $O(n)$ on $G$ given by $(A,v)\cdot B=(AB,v)$, which is free and transitive on $O(n)$, and preserves the fibers $\pi_{V^n}$. It follows that $O(n)\times V^n$ is a trivial principal $O(n)$ bundle over $V^n$, and everything we've done here works out again, in a probably even simpler way, except the subgroup isn't normal I don't believe.